# FPT algorithm for Partial k-tree Isomorphism

Tags: reference-request, graph-isomorphism

H.L. Bodlander in Polynomial algorithms for graph isomorphism and chromatic index on partial $k$-trees given a polynomial time algorithm for graph isomorphism when $k$ is constant.

Is there any FPT algorithm for partial $k$-tree isomorphism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [M. kanté](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/19701) pointed out, it's open whether or not graph isomorphism is FPT when parameterized by tree-width. Furthermore, I don't believe there is any complexity-theoretic barrier to creating an FPT algorithm in this case.

For a survey of what's known about the fixed-parameter tractability of graph isomorphism, see the introduction of my paper with Anuj Dawar and Eryk Kopczyński [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-33293-7_21). In the paper we show graph isomorphism is FPT in the tree-*depth* of a graph, which is a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for graph isomorphism to be FPT in tree-width.

Comment: A non-paywalled version of the paper is available at http://people.csail.mit.edu/adam/Papers/tree-depth.pdf.

Comment: Please note, that the problem is even open for the path / tree *distance* width and only solved for the *rooted* tree distance width and some other restrictions (e.g. root sets with c components). The feedback vertex number is another parameter such that $tw\leq f(fvs)$ and for which GI is in FPT (see [here](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~pascal/docs/feedback_griso_KratschSchw.pdf), but canonization is open AFAIK).

Comment: The link to `mpi-inf.mpg.de` in a [comment](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/52067) above seems to be broken; it's probably meant to point to the following article: _Kratsch, Stefan; Schweitzer, Pascal_, [**Isomorphism for graphs of bounded feedback vertex set number.**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-13731-0_9) In: Kaplan, H. (eds) Algorithm Theory - SWAT 2010. SWAT 2010. Lecture Notes in Computer Science, vol 6139, Springer: Berlin, Heidelberg., pp. 81–92 (2010). [Zbl 1284.05296](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1284.05296).

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime, it was shown that Graph Isomorphism is FPT with respect to the treewidth of the graphs.

Daniel Lokshtanov, Marcin Pilipczuk, Michał Pilipczuk, and Saket Saurabh: Fixed-Parameter Tractable Canonization and Isomorphism Test for Graphs of Bounded Treewidth, SIAM J. Comput. 46(1): 161-189 (2017), https://doi.org/10.1137/140999980.

Answer (score 2):

no FPT algorithm is known. I am wondering whether, under some complexity hypothesis, noone exists.