# Fixed parameter tractable algorithms for graph isomorphism

Tags: graph-isomorphism

What are the future directions in fixed parameter tractability of graphs isomorphism after these two recent papers:

- *[Reduction Techniques for Graph Isomorphism in the Context of Width Parameters](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7238)*,  Yota Otachi, Pascal Schweitzer
- *[Fixed-parameter tractable canonization and isomorphism test for graphs of bounded treewidth](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0818)*,  Daniel Lokshtanov, Marcin Pilipczuk, Michał Pilipczuk, Saket Saurabh

Comment: Have you seen http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=802206 ?

Comment: You seem to be asking "what topics remain in this area that people are not already working on".  Given that you are linking to two very recent papers, if you find their further work sections insufficient, then you should perhaps be asking their authors?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20267/open-problems-related-to-graph-isomorphism/20272 ?

Comment: @Thomas: Have you seen http://www.springerlink.com/index/RTYTQR946FW2X9JL.pdf ?